# .svn directory missing in new repository on Subversion 1.8 on centOS 6.x

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I've done a fresh install of Subversion 1.8.10 on my CentOS server and created first repository.

```
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /var/www/svn/testrepo
cd /var/www/svn/testrepo
$ mkdir trunk
$ mkdir branches
$ mkdir tags
$ svn add *
svn: E155007: '/var/www/svn/testrepo' is not a working copy
```

on further digging the error i realized that **.svn** directory is missing. Following the listing of my testrepo directory.

```
drwxrwxr-x  9 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:06 . 
drwxr-xr-x 11 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:05 .. 
drwxrwxr-x  2 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:06 branches
drwxrwxr-x  2 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:05 conf 
drwxrwsr-x  6 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:05 db 
-r--r--r--  1 dwac dwac    2 Dec 20 05:05 format 
drwxrwxr-x  2 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:05 hooks 
drwxrwxr-x  2 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:05 locks
-rw-rw-r--  1 dwac dwac  246 Dec 20 05:05 README.txt
drwxrwxr-x  2 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:06 tags
drwxrwxr-x  2 dwac dwac 4096 Dec 20 05:06 trunk
```

Is there something that I'm missing ??
I've tried all options I could think of / find but no luck . Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you create your repository you need to checkout first in **different** directory. This directory will be your working copy.

First create repository

```
svnadmin create --fs-type fsfs /var/www/svn/testrepo
```

then your working copy

```
cd $HOME
mkdir svnWorkingCopy
cd svnWorkingCopy
svn checkout  file:///var/www/svn/testrepo .
mkdir trunk
mkdir branches
mkdir tags
svn add *
svn commit
```